# Python equivalent for Curl giving 400 Response

Tags: python, api, curl, python-requests, http-status-code-400

Trying to re-write shell curl to python script with requests module...

My shell script :

```
#!/bin/bash

ip=$1
url=https://xxx.xx.xx.com
secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
expand=computerStatus


curl --silent -X POST "$url/api/computers/search?expand=$expand" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "api-secret-key: $secret" -H "api-version: v1" -d '{"maxItems": 10,"searchCriteria": [{"fieldName": "hostName","stringTest": "equal", "stringValue": "'"$ip"'"}]}' -k > $file
```

above works fine in bash.

I am trying to convert to similar python equivalent

What I tried

```
import json
import requests
import sys

ip = sys.argv[1]

sys_info = []

url=https://xxx.xx.xx.com
secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
expand=computerStatus

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'api-secret-key': secret,
    'api-version': 'v1',
}

params = (
    ('expand', 'expand'),
)

data = '{"maxItems": 10,"searchCriteria": [{"fieldName": "hostName","stringTest": "equal", "stringValue": ip}]}'

response = requests.post('https://url/api/computers/search?expand=expand', headers=headers, params=params, data=data)

print(response)

<Response [400]>
```

I am getting 400 response.. not sure where i am missing in syntax...

Answer (score 1):

data needs to be a dictionary, try this:

```py
data = {
    "maxItems": 10, 
    "searchCriteria": [{"fieldName": "hostName","stringTest": "equal", "stringValue": ip}]
    }
```

Also convert params to a dictionary as well:

```py
 params = {"expand" : expand}
```

And when posting:

```py
response = requests.post(f'https://{url}/api/computers/search', headers=headers, params=params, data=data)

### or alternatively you can

response = requests.post(f'https://{url}/api/computers/search?expand={expand}', headers=headers, data=data)
```

Comment: Hi i still get 400, can you confirm if my  `expand=computerStatus` and `response = requests.post('https://url/api/computers/search?expand=expand', headers=headers, params=params, data=data)` is correct syntatically ? especially expand=expand in above url

Comment: oh right, you don't need params here if you are going to encode it inside the string, basically use f-strings (assuming you are using python 3.6+ or use formatted strings), `requests.post(f'https://url/api/computers/search?expand={expand}', headers=headers, data=data` I will edit my answer accordingly

Comment: thank you,  still getting 400, this time i included url directly instead of substitution, but same result.... shell script works fine ..little weird

Comment: It most likely means the hostname can't be resolved.Like it says.Rather than url/api maybe try localhost:8000/api or 127.0.0.1:8000/api assuming the endpoint is hosted in your computer with the port 8000. Oh, maybe you are trying to literally write url as a string, in that case use f strings like I used for {expand} i.e.:
`response = requests.post(f'https://{url}/api/computers/search?expand={expand}', headers=headers, data=data)
` I edited my answer accordingly again

Comment: yeah seems to network issue i get now `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='https', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /xxx.xx..x..com/api/computers/search?expand=computerStatus (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0DCFDB30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')) `...but i wonder why tis successful when i run it from linux machine the linux script..hmm..thanks for your patience to helping me on this

Comment: It is weird indeed, I don't know at this point, still suspecting there is something wrong with the url. Maybe the whole url gets encoded like `"https://https://x...x.x.x..." `? as your url variable also starts with "https://" and adding {url} to the request.post might make https:// gets repeated

Comment: Hi, just though I did not post secret value here for security reasons, it does have special character like `-:+/= ` along with combination other alphabets is this a problem ?

Comment: @asp that shouldn't be a problem no